# Deployment of Azure Function in Visual Studio Code does not include .jar file

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

An Azure Function that I am building needs to be able to execute a procedure in an Azure SQL Server Database.

I have working Java code in Eclipse (based on @duffmo's answer in [Java DB connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881782/java-db-connection))

I then ported the code to an Azure Function in Visual Studio Code, for deployment to Azure. (Note I have removed security code etc.)  I created the project using `View/Command Palette/Azure Functions - Create New Project`

```
package com.function;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpTrigger-Java". Two ways to invoke
     * it using "curl" command in bash: 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your
     * host}/api/HttpTrigger-Java&code={your function key} 2. curl "{your
     * host}/api/HttpTrigger-Java?name=HTTP%20Query&code={your function key}"
     * Function Key is not needed when running locally, it is used to invoke
     * function deployed to Azure. More details:
     * https://aka.ms/functions_authorization_keys
     */
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydb;loginTimeout=10;user=myuser@myserver;password=mypassword;";


    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        Connection connection = null;
        try {

            connection = createConnection(DEFAULT_DRIVER, DEFAULT_URL,context);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "{call MYDB.MYPROC(?,?}";
            List<Object> parameters = Arrays.asList("Bar", "Foo");
            execute(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(connection);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, ExecutionContext context) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static double execute(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall(sql);
        try {
            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                call.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            call.executeUpdate();

        } finally {
            close(call);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However the line

```
 Class.forName(driver);
```

causes the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

I tried to solve this by

1. Putting the `sqljdbc4.jar` in a "lib" directory
2. Manually adding the following to the pom.xml

   `<dependency>`
        `<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>`
       `<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>`
      `<version>4.0</version>`
     `</dependency>`
3. Trying to [install the jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0) from the terminal via

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=’C:=myPath\myFunction\lib\sqljdbc4.jar'`
    `-DgroupId=package  -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion='4.0' -Dpackaging=jar`
4. [experimented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210769/classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver) with changing the order of 'microsoft' and 'sqlserver' in the DEFAULT_DRIVER string.
5. Try and add SQLJDBC from the new [Java Dependencies view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-howto-add-jar-to-classpath) (see @hemangs answer) - but it does not appear in the list
6. I edited the .classPath as per @asndr's answer in [.classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749388/setting-the-classpath-in-a-visual-studio-code-maven-based-java-project) - note that I did not manage to access the .classPath from within VS Code, but rather via File Explorer - and then ran `view/Command Palette/Java: Clean the java language server workspace`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @nirmal's answer in [Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0)
I did the following:

1. Explorer/Java Dependencies/Maven Dependencies - then clicked on '+'
2. Typed in `mssql-jdbc` and pressed Enter
3. Selected `mssql-jdbc` from com.microsoft.sqlserver
4. This opened the pom.xml within VS Code with the following added

   `<dependency>`

   ```
     <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
     <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>8.3.0.jre14-preview</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. I changed the version number to `6.1.0.jre8` (the higher version caused compile errors)
6. Saved
7. VS Code asked me if I want to 'A build file was modified. Do you want to synchronize the Java classpath/configuration?'
8. I said yes, and then it worked.

What seems to be crucial is to edit the pom.xml from within VS Code. It seems that when I edited it outside of VS Code, then VS Code did not trigger a synchronization of the configuration.