# How to add username , email and password on firebase

Tags: java, android, mobile

i'm begginer on firebase with android and i don't know how to use all features anyways...i have a signup form and i want to add username except email and password to database.Also i dont't know how to keep user logged in on my app if has connect to account at least one time.

Comment: Try to search Firebase tutorial's on Youtube. Mostly basic's are covered in 6-7 videos. But always go for recently added video's.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a class that allows you to connect to the database. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881782/java-db-connection))

Then you can use the `stmt.executeUpdate(query)` method to add something in your db. You can find more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/statement-object-example.htm). (In the link I mentioned above is part of the update method `update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters)`)

I highly recommend you to see how sql queries work [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/), specifically the one about `INSERT INTO`.